# How to access all sessions on a Spring webflux server instance / hook into sessions lifecycle?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to implement a [Back-Channel Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html) endpoint on a Spring webflux application (`spring-cloud-gateway`).

For that, I need to retrieve user session "statically" to:

- remove the authorized client matching an `issuer` and `subject`, but without the context of user session
- if the removed authorized client was the last one (with authorization-code) for this user, invalidate the session. But only if there is no more authorized client: if you are logged onto Google and Facebook with the same client, the session on this client should remain active when you logout from only one of the two.

The current `ServerWebExchange` is initiated by the OIDC provider itself and, as user browser is not involved, there is no session cookie.

Instead, a "logout" JWT is provided as request body (this is where I find the `issuer` and the `subject` which should be enough to identify the session to invalidate and the authorized client to remove).

With Servlets, this problem can be addressed by implementing `HttpSessionListener, HttpSessionIdListener` (and using a `ServletListenerRegistrationBean`) to build and maintain indexes of sessions by `issuer` and user `subject` each time an authorized client is added or removed.

Unfortunately, `spring-cloud-gateway` is a reactive application and I couldn't find equivalent session listeners for `WebSession`.

Any clue on how I could proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @elyorbek-ibrokhimov does not answer my need which is to hook into the sessions lifecycle but it definitely put me on the right track. Many thanks to him. Here is how I implemented it (with inspiration from the `MaxIdleTimeInMemoryWebSessionStore`):

```java
@Bean
WebSessionManager webSessionManager(WebSessionStore webSessionStore) {
    DefaultWebSessionManager webSessionManager = new DefaultWebSessionManager();
    webSessionManager.setSessionStore(webSessionStore);
    return webSessionManager;
}

@Bean
WebSessionStore webSessionStore(ServerProperties serverProperties) {
    return new SpringAddonsWebSessionStore(serverProperties.getReactive().getSession().getTimeout());
}

public static interface WebSessionListener {

    default void sessionCreated(WebSession session) {
    }

    default void sessionRemoved(String sessionId) {
    }
}

static class SpringAddonsWebSessionStore implements WebSessionStore {
    private final InMemoryWebSessionStore delegate = new InMemoryWebSessionStore();
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<WebSessionListener> webSessionListeners = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<WebSessionListener>();

    private final Duration timeout;

    public SpringAddonsWebSessionStore(Duration timeout) {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }
    
    public void addWebSessionListener(WebSessionListener listener) {
        webSessionListeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<WebSession> createWebSession() {
        return delegate.createWebSession().doOnSuccess(this::setMaxIdleTime)
                .doOnSuccess(session -> webSessionListeners.forEach(l -> l.sessionCreated(session)));
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<WebSession> retrieveSession(String sessionId) {
        return delegate.retrieveSession(sessionId);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> removeSession(String sessionId) {
        webSessionListeners.forEach(l -> l.sessionRemoved(sessionId));
        return delegate.removeSession(sessionId);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<WebSession> updateLastAccessTime(WebSession webSession) {
        return delegate.updateLastAccessTime(webSession);
    }

    private void setMaxIdleTime(WebSession session) {
        session.setMaxIdleTime(this.timeout);
    }
}
```

Now, I can register a custom authorized client repository against this `WebSessionStore` and have it be notified with `sessionCreated` and `sessionRemoved` events to update its own indexes.

Comment: How it can be done if we use spring session in redis

Comment: I believe that the `delegate` in the custom `WebSessionStore` won't be an `InMemoryWebSessionStore`. I've not need it so far so can't tell exactly. Maybe inspect what is the `WebSessionStore` in your runtime, how it is instantiated, and change the `delegate` declaration and instantiation above?

Answer (score 3):

One possible way is overriding default `WebSessionManager` configuration and setting session store with manually created `InMemoryWebSessionStore` bean.

```java
@Configuration
public class SessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebSessionManager webSessionManager (WebSessionStore webSessionStore) {
        DefaultWebSessionManager webSessionManager = new DefaultWebSessionManager();
        webSessionManager.setSessionStore(webSessionStore);
        return webSessionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryWebSessionStore inMemoryWebSessionStore() {
        return new InMemoryWebSessionStore();
    }

}
```

Then in logout logic we can inject `InMemoryWebSessionStore` bean, retrive all sessions and perform logout:

```java
@Service
public class SessionService {

    private InMemoryWebSessionStore webSessionStore;

    public SessionService(InMemoryWebSessionStore webSessionStore) {
        this.webSessionStore = webSessionStore;
    }

    private Mono<Void> performLogout(String issuer, String subject) {
       String sessionId = webSessionStore.getSessions()
                .entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> shouldBeRemoved(issuer, subject, e.getValue()))
                .findFirst() // assuming issuer and subject combination is always unique
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .orElse("dummy-session-id");
       return webSessionStore.removeSession(sessionId);
    }

    private boolean shouldBeRemoved(String issuer, String subject, WebSession session) {
        OidcUser oidcUser = oidcUserFromSession(session);
        return issuer.equals(oidcUser.getIssuer().toString()) && subject.equals(oidcUser.getSubject());
    }

    private OidcUser oidcUserFromSession(WebSession session) {
        SecurityContext securityContext = session.getAttribute(WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository
                .DEFAULT_SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_ATTR_NAME);
        return (OidcUser) securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helped and put me on the right to track to implement an equivalent of `HttpSessionListener` for `WebSession`. If you are curious to see how I used the code exposed in my answer to implement a reactive Back-Channel Logout, it is there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/webflux/spring-addons-webflux-client/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/reactive/SpringAddonsBackChannelLogoutBeans.java

Comment: Its servlet equivalent is here: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-client/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/synchronised/SpringAddonsBackChannelLogoutBeans.java

Comment: Glad to be of help. Nice work!