# How to catch Session Destroy event in Spring Cloud Gateway (reactive stack)?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I would like to catch the session destroy event in Spring Cloud Gateway (reactive stack)

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway app setup and would like to catch a logout event (something like session destroyed event) in that app. I know how to catch the event after logging out (using ServerLogoutSuccessHandler), but I want to catch the event when someone closes the browser. I had it prepared earlier using an application that had no dependencies to the cloud gateway, only oauth2 and I had it done as follows:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

@Component
class LogoutEvent implements HttpSessionListener {
    
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // some logic
        HttpSessionListener.super.sessionDestroyed(se);
    }

}
```

thanks to this, when there was a session timeout, I could handle it in this event.

Now I would like to do the same thing using Spring Cloud Gateway (reactive stack). I have timeout defined in properties using `server.reactive.session.timeout: 900s`  and I would like to catch session destroy in code.

Is there any possibility to catch such an event in Spring Cloud Gateway (reactive stack)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75716228/how-to-access-all-sessions-on-a-spring-webflux-server-instance-hook-into-sessi/75750492#75750492